# Robot framework logger not adding info to debugfile if used inside resource file

Tags: python, logging, robotframework

I am having a Robot suite in the following structure

```
S_SUITE
├── datasource.txt
├── dinesh.robot
├── __init__.py
└── test.py
```

**dinesh.robot**

```
 *** Settings ***
Library        test.py
Resource    datasource.txt
*** Test Cases ***
DEMO
    Log    "Testcase start"
    sample
    Log    "Testcase end"
```

**datasource.txt**

```
*** Settings ***
Library   __init__.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from robot.api import logger
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
# These below messages are not seen in debug_record.txt
logger.info('Expected to see this!!!')
logger.error('At least this in debug_record')

def hai():
  # These below messages are also not seen in debug_record.txt
  BuiltIn().log("this is an info message", "INFO")
  logger.info('this is an info too')

hai()
```

**test.py**

```
from robot.api import logger
def sample():
    # Only the below logger.info is added into debug_record.txt
    logger.info('THIS IS INSIDE SAMPLE')
```

I am running this suite as

```
 robot --loglevel debug --debugfile debug_record.txt S_SUITE/
```

When I run this suite, the message `THIS IS INSIDE SAMPLE` alone is getting added into the `debug_record.txt`. The `datasource.txt` from `dinesh.robot` is including `__init__.py` file. This file has few `logger.info` statements which are never getting logged into the `debug_record.txt`.

Along with `logger.info`, I have also tried `logger.error` & `BuiltIn().log`as well. But no luck. I have noticed that `logger.error` is printing error in console and also sending the same info to `log.html`, but not `debug_record.txt`

It looks like `logger` is adding info to `debug_record.txt` only in the places where logger is used inside the testcase (i.e while the testcase running) and if used by `Resource` of a suite, it is not adding the info to `debug_record.txt`.

How can I rectify this issue ?

**debug_record.txt:**

```
[dsivaji@FADL155 ~]$ cat debug_record.txt
==============================================================================
20190307 10:48:34.845 - INFO - + START SUITE: S SUITE [ ]
==============================================================================
20190307 10:48:34.858 - INFO - +- START SUITE: S SUITE.Dinesh [ ]
==============================================================================
20190307 10:48:34.859 - INFO - +-- START TEST: DEMO [ ]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20190307 10:48:34.860 - INFO - +--- START KW: BuiltIn.Log [ "Testcase start" ]
20190307 10:48:34.860 - INFO - "Testcase start"
20190307 10:48:34.861 - INFO - +--- END KW: BuiltIn.Log (1)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
20190307 10:48:34.861 - INFO - +--- START KW: test.Sample [ ]
20190307 10:48:34.862 - INFO - THIS IS INSIDE SAMPLE
20190307 10:48:34.863 - INFO - +--- END KW: test.Sample (1)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
20190307 10:48:34.863 - INFO - +--- START KW: BuiltIn.Log [ "Testcase end" ]
20190307 10:48:34.864 - INFO - "Testcase end"
20190307 10:48:34.865 - INFO - +--- END KW: BuiltIn.Log (1)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20190307 10:48:34.866 - INFO - +-- END TEST: DEMO (7)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20190307 10:48:34.869 - INFO - +- END SUITE: S SUITE.Dinesh (22)
==============================================================================
20190307 10:48:34.871 - INFO - + END SUITE: S SUITE (141)
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has many sides. But what you see in the debug file is in my opinion correct.

1) Importing libraries using static library API
Robot Framework does not execute the code, when it finds the keywords from your libraries. Instead Robot Framework uses reflection to discover the keywords. Therefore when the your static library is imported, logging does not happen.

But the importing system is complex and therefore the above does not always true. Depending on the used library API and do you import module or class, discovery of the keywords happens in different way. Example if you import class and log from the library **init** that should appear in the debug file.

2) Loggin from keywords which is not executed.
The keywords which are not not executed, do not generate logging.

3) Logging from executed keyword
As you said this is logged and it is expected to appear in the log file.